# Uploading Docker Images to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create a workflow where developers in my organisation can upload docker images to our AWS ECR. The following commands work :

Step-1: Get Token

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <repo-url>
```

Step-2: Tag the already built image

```
docker tag <local-image:tag> <ecr-repo-url>:latest
```

Step-3: Finally Push

```
docker push <ecr-repo-url>:latest
```

Now this works absolutely fine.

However as I am trying to automate the above steps.  **I will NOT have AWS CLI configured on end users machine**. **So Step-1 will fail for the end user**

So two quick queries:

1. Can I get the token from a remote machine and Step-2 and Step-3 can happen from client
2. Can I do all the three steps in remote and I have a service that uploads the local docker image to the remote server which in turn will take care of tag - push

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping that the end-user will have docker installed

In that case you can make use [AWS CLI](https://hub.docker.com/r/garland/aws-cli-docker/) docker image to obtain the token from ECR.

Answer (score 0):

The token itself is just a temporary password so whether you use the AWS CLI on the remote server or not it will be valid for the Docker credentials.

You of also have the option of using the AWS SDK that you could package with a small application to perform this action, such as [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.get_authorization_token) although you would need to ensure that the host itself has the relevant programming language configured.

Alternatively if you want this to be automated you could actually look at using a CI/CD pipeline.

GitHub has [Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), BitBucket has [Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) and GitLab has arguably the most [CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/) built into it. This would have these services perform all of the above actions for you.

As a final suggestion you could use [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) within a [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) to build your image and then tag and deploy it to ECR for you. This will be automated by a trigger and not require any permanent infrastructure.

More information about this option is available in the [Build a Continuous Delivery Pipeline for Your Container Images with Amazon ECR as Source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source/) article.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the CI/CD pipeline. Basically I am creating an enterprise app where people can pull , push and run images on the fly. So  local > ECR > FarGate is the model. To your answer, if I spawn an EC2 instance that has the AWS CLI and I create an  API that gives the token. Is that the correct understanding ? Do you have a code snippet / example

Comment: Yes you can use the remote instance to generate a token. Regarding the API style solution take a look at these API Gateway examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html. The Lambda would need to use the SDK, each language is slightly different but should have documentation for the method for example https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.get_authorization_token